# Deleting all objects in the document array MongoDB PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have array in document in mongo collection, i need delete all objects in "phone" array.

```
"_id": "id",
"email": "Name@google.com",
"phone": {
    "1": "+1 00000000000",
    "2": "+1 00000000000",
    "3": "+1 00000000000",
    "4": "+1 00000000000",
    "5": "+1 00000000000",
    "6": "+1 00000000000",
    "7": "+1 00000000000",
    "8": "+1 00000000000",
    "9": "+1 00000000000"
 }
```

If i use:

```
 $email = "Name@google.com";
 $col->update(array("email"=>$email), array('$unset'=>array("dictionary"=> true)));
```

I delete all and "phone" array to, how i make delete all objects, bat save a "phone" array in my document?

Comment: Just `array('$set' => array( 'phone' => array() ) )` in the update. That set's `phone` to `{}` with nothing inside it.

Comment: In Mongo database displays [ ] instead { }

Comment: You're right of course. PHP is kind of funny like that. The `$set` still applies of course but the "empty object" you want already has many solutions for PHP here.

Comment: I tried to add an object to this array    $col->update(array("email"=>$email), array('$set'=>array("phone.1"=>"+1 000000000")));   but got an error      "phone": [
        null,
        "+1 000000000"
    ]

Comment: Look at the big box above your question and click on the link. There are at least 5 well endorsed ways to get the `{}` result when sent to Mongo that are shown there. What will be sent to MongoDB follows the same rules that JSON serialization does. At least with respect to `{}` and `[]`

Comment: I looked at the links, and did not understand anything. I study the PHP and Mongo  weeks. I read and tried to substitute a solution for my code but it did not work out :(

Comment: I decided :))) Thank you very much Neil Lunn